# Where should I write the script that fills new data in my updated schema?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, migration, schema

I am working on a web app that already has a schema in place (aka in prod) with a certain number of tables (A, B, C...).

Table A has an attribute that corresponds to an `enum` from table B. Problem is that I can have only one item of that `enum` list in my dedicated column in table A. But I want my objects from table A to have many of them. So I created a join table A_B and a `has_many through` association with my table B.

The first consequence is that I need to fill my join table with data from the previous schema architecture. To be clearer, they were objects from table A that were associated with one element of the table B enum. I need to report these simple relationships (only one element from `enum` list in table B is associated with table A objects) in my newly created join table.

Here's the type of things I'd like to do:

```
list_of_ids = []
Model_A.where(attribute: 0).each { |r| list_of_ids << r.id }

a.each { |el| A_B.create(tableA_id: el, tableB_id: 0) }
```

Where should I write and execute these lines of code that will update my data ?

Comment: I think you have to put this logic in a migration file right after you created the join table (you could even put this logic in the same migration file that create the join table so it would modify the DB structure and update the data accordingly "at the same time"). Also, you can improve your code with `list_of_ids = ModelA.where(attribute: 0).pluck(:id)`

Comment: I was hesitating between migration and rake tasks. I understand the arguments from ruby_newbie answer. Why would a migration would be more appropriate in that case ? (cool refacto @MrYoshiji thanks)

Comment: It would be more appropriate because you have to update your current data with the new DB structure (it's mandatory, your app would crash otherwise). Using a rake task is error prone: you could run your migrations and forget to run the rake task (unless your migration invoke the rake task, which lead to the question: "why have a rake task for this because I only want to run it once at this exact point in my project's life? why not directly put it in the migration?").

Comment: this makes total sense thanks @MrYoshiji. To be sure I understood well how migrations work, once I create the migration that handles the logic of putting new data, these new data will be "injected" only once (when running rake db:migrate) ? Future rake db:migrate won't duplicate these data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comments, I would put this "data-update" logic in the same migration file of the join table creation.

Why in a migration file?

- the data conversion needs to be done only once, AFTER you created the join table and BEFORE you remove the column which holds the foreign key. If you do this data conversion after the column removal, you will get an error saying that your code is trying to access column that does not exist anymore.
- the migration is responsible for changing the DB structure AND for the data integrity.

Why not a rake task?

- rake tasks are meant to be run several times, not only once. The usual tasks are "send_emails", "update_expiration_dates", "compute_cache", "close_inactive_users_account", etc.
- the data you have before your conversion has_many -> HABTM have to be updated to follow the new structure. the rake task could not be ran, and then your data would not be updated, therefore you would loose the association between your models (removing the foreign_key column before running the rake task would make you loose this data).
- your data-conversion logic must happen after the migration creating the join table and BEFORE the migration removing the foreign key's column. There are clear way to say to your rails app: "do this migration, then stop, run this task, then do this migration". It will run the migrations consecutively. If you have these 2 migrations pending, they will be run at once unless you specify otherwise (which is not common at all), and then you rake task will be useless because it relies on the fact that the foreign key column still exists.

Comment: Funny, I was thinking your answer is clear and _mine_ is messy +1

Answer (score 2):

#### In addition to MrYoshiji's answer (too long for comments):

Migrations are intended for one-off changes to both database schemas *and* the data therein. The official [guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data) mentions this, too.

In your case, populating the join table is an appropriate thing to do in a migration. Otherwise data would be left in an invalid or incorrect state vis-a-vis the schema and model changes you have made. Running migrations is a typical step in deploying a Rails app. Since you probably do not want to deploy without updating the data, having it as part of a migration is a great solution. In contrast, if you created a custom rake task to update the data then you would need to remember to run it manually after deploying or add it as a deployment step, neither of which is a very good option.

Comment: Yeah...what MrYoshiji said :)